# How to update a nested json using scala play framework?

Tags: scala, play-json

I am trying to update a json value present within a json using Scala play framework.Instead of updating the value it is appending the value.

```
val newJsonString = """{"P123": 25}"""
val jsonStringAsJsValue = Json.parse("""{"counter_holders": {"Peter": 25}}""")
//jsonStringAsJsValue: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"counter_holders":{"Peter":25}}

val jsonTransformer = (__ \"counter_holders" ).json.update(__.read[JsValue].map{o => Json.parse(newJsonString)})

jsonStringAsJsValue.transform(jsonTransformer).get.as[JsValue]
//Now getting this jsvalue
//play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"counter_holders":{"Peter":25,"P123":25}}
//But need  this jsvalue
//play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"counter_holders":{"P123":25}}
```

Any help on this will be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the `update` method docs:

> (`__` \ 'key).json.update(reads) is the most complex Reads[JsObject]
> but the most powerful:
>
> - copies the whole JsValue => A
> - applies the passed Reads[A] on JsValue => B
> - deep merges both JsValues (A ++ B) so B overwrites A identical branches Please note that if you have prune a branch in B, it is still
>   in A so you'll see it in the result Example:
>
>   ```
>   {{{ val js = Json.obj("key1" -> "value1", "key2" -> "value2")
>   js.validate(__.json.update((__ \ 'key3).json.put(JsString("value3"))))
>   => JsSuccess({"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"},) }}}
>   ```

Therefore the behaviour you see is as expected. If you want to take that approach, of updating using the path, you can use the method [prune](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsPath$.html#prune(js:play.api.libs.json.JsValue):play.api.libs.json.JsResult%5Bplay.api.libs.json.JsObject%5D). For example you can do:

```
val newJsonString = """{"P123": 25}"""
val jsonStringAsJsValue = Json.parse("""{"counter_holders": {"Peter": 25}}""")
//jsonStringAsJsValue: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"counter_holders":{"Peter":25}}

val jsonTransformer = (__ \"counter_holders" ).json
  .update(__.read[JsValue].map{o => Json.parse(newJsonString)})

val jsonTransformerDelete = (__ \"counter_holders" \ "Peter" ).json.prune

jsonStringAsJsValue.transform(jsonTransformer).flatMap(_.transform(jsonTransformerDelete)) match {
  case JsSuccess(value, _) =>
    println(value)
  case JsError(errors) =>
    println(errors)
}
```

which will produce the wanted behaviour. You can find it in [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2KdiggNPSCyn3fhcmQa40Q).