# How to replace value in json using scala play json

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm at scala play 2.6.10
I have a json:

```json
{"_id": {"$oid": "VALUE"}, "anotherField": "anotherValue"}
```

The goal is to get rid of `{"$oid": "VALUE"}` and put `"VALUE"` as the value for `"_id"` field.

Expected result:

```json
{"_id": "VALUE", "anotherField": "anotherValue"}
```

Tried this one:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonTransformers

i have absolutely no idea how to combine

- extract specific branch value
- "prune" of JsObject
- "update" deleted JsObject with JsString.

BTW, is there any simpler API for doing it? This one is way too complex.

Comment: I've seen similar examples. Can't make it work since I "update" JsObject to JsString. Don't understand how to express it with that Json DSL

Comment: Look like MongoDB extended syntax, so rather use a dedicated lib

Comment: what is dedicated lib? can mongo-scala-driver interact with scala case classes directly?

Comment: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/json/overview.html#documents-and-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a nested json using scala play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280699/how-to-update-a-nested-json-using-scala-play-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about the update documentation at [How to update a nested json using scala play framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280699/how-to-update-a-nested-json-using-scala-play-framework) In your example you can do something like this:

```scala
val jsonString = """{"_id": {"$oid": "VALUE"}, "anotherField": "anotherValue"}
                   |""".stripMargin

val jsonTransformer = (__ \ "_id").json.update(__.read[JsObject].map { _ => JsString("Value") })
Json.parse(jsonString).transform(jsonTransformer) match {
  case JsSuccess(value, _) =>
    println(value)
  case JsError(errors) =>
    println(errors)
}
```

It outputs:

```json
{"anotherField":"anotherValue","_id":"Value"}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PxaeiIFQSJKOFdMUvy9uGA).